# VMware Workstation VM has no network connection on bridge mode

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I just set up a Win10 VMware Workstation Pro and it works like a charm - except for the network connection. I want to be able to connect to the internet from the VM itself, so I went to "`settings > Network`" and chose "`Bridged`" and also checked "Replicate physical network connection state".

Now what I expected was that upon startup the virtual machine would connect to the internet (Device Status has both boxes checked that say "`Connected`" and "`Connect at power on`").

Sadly I am running into "No identified network" as connection status - did I miss something? VMware seems to be running just fine - considering the little images:

[image]

Running `/ipconfig` gives me an ip with a subnet-mask `255.255.0.0` - my host system automatically configures itself with `255.255.255.0` - might that be a problem?

**EDIT**

Configuring the network as "NAT" works, but Bridge-Mode does not work sadly - I'd love to go with Bridge mode.

Comment: [check this link on VMware communities](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Network-Bridge-Mode-Not-Working-Windows-10-Host/m-p/1407024#M81215)

Comment: For Bridged Mode to work, the Guest machine will get its IP address from the main network that the Host connects to. Is this the way you have it set up?